# Is there any other way to solve this question?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sixth term of an arithmetic progression is $2$, and its common difference is greater than $1$. Show that the value of the common difference of the progression so that the product of the first, fourth and fifth therm is greatest is $\frac{8}{5}$.

I did it with the concept of Maxima and Minima. Can someone suggest any other methods, something that is purely Algebra

Comment: By "concept of maxima and minima" you mean with calculus and derivatives, or what?

Comment: Yeah, that only, i.e. with calculus and derivatives.

Comment: In general, and even in this particular case, I doubt there's something as simple and shorter as calculus to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, I thought that weighted AM-GM inequality would do it but i was not able to figure out the coefficients of $a_1,a_4$ and $a_5$, you see i am pretty new to the concept of weighted AM-GM.

Comment: I didn't even know about "weighted AM-GM", but anyway: I can't see how could that solve this problem.

Comment: Well, what i tried was $$\frac{ka_1+la_4+ma_5}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{klm\cdot a_1a_2a_3}$$, such that $ka_1+la_4+ma_5$, and then using the properties of the arithmetic sequence, I equated the coefficients, but then i could not proceed furhter.

Comment: In an AP how can how can the product of the 1st 4th and 5th term be GREATEST?

Comment: I think the question doesn't state that they are the greatest of all the possible products of any three terms in an A.P., in my opinion it says that the product of  $a_1,a_4,$ and $a_5$ br the greatest of all the values it can attain.

Comment: @user350331 Take $a=12;d=-2$ Since you said difference >1, AP can be increasing or decreasing..

Comment: If $d=100$ then according to the question $$a_6=2$$ $$or, a+5(100)=2$$ $$or, a=-498$$. So, we get, $a_1=a=-498, a_4=-198$ and $a_5=-98$ and their product $a_1a_4a_5=(-498)(-198)(-98)<0$ but what if $d=\frac{3}{2}$, then the product of the three terms comes out to be positive, so what the question is trying to state is what is the value of $d$ so that the product $a_1a_4a_5$ is greater than when any other value of $d$ is selected. It does not say that for what value of  $d$ the product $a_1a_4a_5$ would be greater than $a_pa_qa_r$, where $1\lt p,q,r \lt n$

Comment: @user350331 Look at my new $d$

Comment: But $d=-2 \lt 1$ so the condition that you considered is not as per the question. And as $d \gt 1$, the nthe A.P. is obviously increasing.

Comment: @user350331 Difference of $a$ and $b$ means $|a-b|$.

Comment: Refer [Arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). It clearly states that d is the difference between terms of the arithmetic progression, not the absolute difference.

Comment: The question says clearly $\;d>1\;$ , so it is an increasing AP, and then it is asked, with $\;a_6=2\;$ ,for what value of $\;d\;$ is the product $\;a_1a_4a_5\;$ maximal. Perhaps the problem has no solution or whatever, but the question, off the top of my head, looks fine to me.\

Comment: @Joanpemo, so what do you think how would the approach with weighted AM-GM work.

Comment: @user350331 I've no idea, honest. I'd do with calculus and it seems, in my opinion, the fastest, simplest way.

Comment: @Joanpemo, can you refer someone who might help me in solving it by weighted AM-GM or with any other method, just for the sake of learning.